# GLSL for simple water surface effects

Tags: glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm looking for some pointers on how to implement simple water surface effects in OpenGL ES 2.0.   Nothing fancy like reflection or refraction, just a basic ripple/wave effect that modulates over time.   Performance is critical.  I'm assuming this will be best done in a shader.

Any pointers on how to best handle this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an old trick to simulate water waves & ripples using minimum effort in terms of equations. It's used in many places, and I can't find the original, but you can grab it, for example, from [here](http://www.fabiensanglard.net/fluide/).

You'll need 2 textures, each containing just height. Simulation is done by ping-ponging between them (using one as a source and second as destination each time).

When rendering, you might need to derive surface normal from the neighbour heights.