# Core Image vs Core Graphics

Tags: ios

I am making an application that uses basic core Graphics functions . The Application runs reasonably well on Ipad2, but there is a performance hit on Ipad3 due to retina display, which causes drawing to be done on number of pixels 4 times to the earlier. I tried some hacks to improve performance, but since drawing takes place on gestures in my code, I think I will have to switch on to some other alternative. I was wanting to ask if Core Image provides all the functionalities that can be performed using Core Graphics, so that I may use GPU Processing capability. If not, what could be the best alternative so that I can use the same functionalities with a better processing capability.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the performance drop is because of the increased number of pixels?

Comment: Yes. Because the performance shows some improvement when some drawing operations are removed or portions of the screens are drawn instead of the whole screen.

Answer (score 11):

Core Image and Core Graphics are very different. Core Image is an **image processing technology**. You can apply pre-made filters like sepia, black and white, and color invert, or you can create custom filters. Core Graphics is a rendering API utilizing Quartz 2D technologies that allows for complex drawing.

Brad Larson's GPUImage is a great alternative/addition to Core Image. You can find it [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#readme).

If you want improved performance, you can try a low level API like OpenGL. It's difficult to learn, but here are a few links to get you started:

- [iPhone OpenGL ES – 8 Great Resources For Learning](http://maniacdev.com/2009/04/8-great-resources-for-learning-iphone-opengl-es/) - From ManiacDev, self-explanatory
- [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) - Apple's own documentation, thorough, a good start
- [iOS based OpenGL ES programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074688/ios-based-opengl-es-programming) - Some more resources for getting started
- [OpenGL ES 2.0 for iPhone Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial)  - Good Ray Wenderlich introduction
- [Pro OpenGL ES for iOS](http://www.apress.com/9781430238409) - Great Apress book but not for beginners

Answer (score 1):

A year late, I know, but take a look at WWDC 2010 Sessions on Core Animation: 424,and 425.  Both are important, but there are some good details on performance tuning in 425 at about the 11:00 mark.

The short synopsis, is that there are three potential bottlenecks, and you need to identify, optimize, and keep iterating until you get a smooth 60 FPS.  The potential bottlenecks are:

- read bandwidth
- write bandwidth
- processing / rendering passes.

The 425 session (Core Animation in Practice, Part 2) covers techniques for dealing with the above.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/